# xrandr causing various cursor problems

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, xrandr, cursor

I am using ubuntu 15.10 on a MacBook Pro 2014 (Retina screen) and I am having to use xrandr to scale the HDMI output so that everything on my (normal DPI) 1080p external monitor isn't ridiculously small.

My issue is that firstly the cursor on the external display is always off diagonally by a few pixels, enough to make selecting text a complete pain in the arse. The point at which the cursor 'clicks' seems to be about two thirds down towards the lower right corner of the cursor instead of top left pixel. Very strange and very infuriating.

Secondly occasionally my cursor disappears completely, or only on one screen. The effects of the cursor can still be seen (i.e. I can still click, still hover over buttons and see them highlight etc) but not knowing exactly where the cursor is is driving me mad. A quick fix is to do Alt+F2 and enter 'r' but this then means running the external monitor commands again, which doesn't always go smoothly... a bit of a farce when I'm meant to be working.

The command I am using is:

`xrandr --output HDMI2 --scale 2x2 --mode 1920x1080 --fb 6400x2160 --pos 0x0
sleep 5
xrandr --output eDP1  --scale 1x1 --mode 2560x1600 --pos 3840x900`

The sleep is needed as for some reason it takes a few moments for the initial command to settle down!

Any advice would be great.

EDIT: Worth noting that the cursor offset problem has only appeared recently, although not sure whether it coincided with upgrading to 15.10 from 15.04. The disappearing cursor has been happening for a while though.

EDIT 2: Another point, this xrandr setup does seem to be buggy as hell - X seems to crash at least once per day. Would be amazing to resolve that too.